# What do I initialize this to?

Tags: java

I'm learning methods and I'm starting with finding the max value out of three integers. I try to run this and it tells me that I haven't initialized `result`. I know I didn't, but I don't know what exactly to initialize it to. I probably messed up or forgot something in the code as well, so if you could point it out to me, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinMaxAvg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 5;
        int j = 2;
        int k = 3;
        int l = max(i, j, k);
        System.out.println ("The maximum of " + i + " and " + j + " and " + k + " is " + l);
    }

    public static int max (int num1, int num2, int num3) {
        int result;

        if (num1 > num2 || num1 > num3) {
            result = num1;
        } else if (num2 > num1 || num2 > num3) {
            result = num2;
        } else if (num3 > num1 || num3 > num2) {
            result = num3;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static int max (int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    int max = num1;

    if (num2 > max ) {
        max = num2;
    } 

    if (num3 > max ) {
        max = num3;
    }

    return max ;
}
```

java is pretty cool though, so if you want to get fancy, do this

```
public static int max(int... args)
{
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int a : args)
    {
        if (a > max)
        {
            max = a;
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize

```
int result;
```

as

```
int result = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are declaring method all variable inside method acts as a local variable and you must have to initialize that before using it.
try this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinMaxAvg {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int i = 5;
int j = 2;
int k = 3;
int l = max(i, j, k);
System.out.println ("The maximum of " + i +
   " and " + j + " and " + k + " is " + l);
   }

public static int max (int num1, int num2, int num3) {

int result=0;//initialize here by 0 or any other value

if (num1 > num2 || num1 > num3) {
   result = num1;

} else if (num2 > num1 || num2 > num3) {
   result = num2;

} else if (num3 > num1 || num3 > num2) {
   result = num3;

}

return result;
}
}
```

if you still want to use `int result` without initializing it then you must declare it as instance variable like:

```
 public class MinMaxAvg {
    static int result;
    }
```

More information you can visit this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Answer (score 0):

You'd initialize local variables with some default value `int result = Integer.Integer.MIN_VALUE`